# Download .ipa build via App Store Connect API

Tags: app-store-connect

Due to some unique quality and regulatory requirements in our organisation, we need to be able to download a .ipa build from App Store Connect, in order to be able to compare it against a locally built binary. I appreciate this is an unusual requirement, but it is non-negotiable.

Clearly there is no way to do this via the App Store Connect web interface, so I've been looking at the App Store Connect API. However it is ambiguous from the documentation, whether it is possible to use this to download an `.ipa` build.

Does anyone know if this is possible, and how one might go about doing it if so please?

Comment: yes, it's possible with the help Apple Configurator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apple does not provide any way of retrieving an upload app/IPA. It's neither possible through App Store Connect nor the App Store Connect API.

You can only check entitlements and additional build information in the App Store Connect interface. For that go to App Store Connect > My Apps > Activity > All Builds > Click on the build

(Fastlane does also not provide any way, because Apple does not expose the data. It uses the "web API", i.e. has access to more information than the "standard" App Store Connect API)

Comment: no, We can download .IPA file from Appstore. With the help of Apple Configurator, we can download .IPA file.

Answer (score 6):

We can download IPA file with the help of Apple Configurator. Follow below steps to download IPA file.

- Download Apple Configurator 2 app on your MAC.
- Connect your iPhone with MAC and Apple ID should be same in apple Configurator and iPhone.
- New window will display with app count badge in All Devices Tab.
- Right click on your connected device in Apple Configurator and select Add and then Apps.
- Process will complete and Popup will show with options, no need to click any option and go to this path

**~/Library/Group Containers/K36BKF7T3D.group.com.apple.configurator/Library/Caches/Assets/TemporaryItems/MobileApps/**

- Save IPA file in your directory
  -Now stop Apple Configurator

Comment: This is a released app on the app store right? not an unreleased build sitting in AppStoreConnect?

Comment: Yes, Released app is possible with apple configurator

Comment: unreleased build, we can download from xcode and apple connect account, but make sure that should be in my account or xcode.

Comment: Just used this to retrieve an otherwise lost .ipa file!  A nice trick!

Comment: I've followed the upper 4 steps but My MobileApps/ folder is empty. additionally app has been installed to my iPhone from Apple Configurator.

Comment: I tried today, it's working fine. Can you please follow again above steps and make sure don't click on any option when popup will appear just go to the above path when popup will appear.

Comment: It works but the app only appears for a few seconds after it is downloaded before being deleted from the folder again so watch the folder and copy as soon as you see it.

Comment: It's showing while the popup showing, if you choose any option from popup then it will remove from folder. If you don't choose any option it will show while popup.

The ipa folder appears when the popup is displayed. If you select any option from the popup, the folder will be removed. If you not select any option, the ipa folder will continue to display while the popup is active.

Answer (score 1):

If the file gets deleted before you can copy it, you can use this command:

```
watch -n 0.1 find "~/Library/Group\ Containers/K36BKF7T3D.group.com.apple.configurator" -iname "*.ipa" -exec 'cp -r {} ~/Downloads \;'
```

When it's downloaded it will copy it to the Downloads folder. You're welcome.

Part of the credits to my colleague DaniÃ«l.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I know this question is aimed at Downloading Appstore/Testflight builds, specifically, but wanted to provide this answer for others who find your question while looking for it from anywhere.

You can download iOS .ipa from Firebase distribution, as well as for Android .apks. But you do need to have the right permissions.

[image]
I just did it 5 minutes ago. See ☝️?

Go into App Distribution > find your app scheme/variant > expand build number > see if you have a Download button. If you don't, your company needs to bump your permissions up a bit higher.
[image]

Keep in mind that firebase apps can experience limitations when interacting with Apple SDK features, though, like SIWA. You'd need to use Testflight to test things like that if they don't work for you (we have decent devs and never could get it working on Firebase builds).

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm answering pretty old question, but if someone would still need this..
It seems Apple has added in the meantime way how to download artifacts, if you build it through `Xcode Cloud`.

Go to:
`Xcode Cloud` -> `Builds` -> Expand Archiving build step -> Click Build number -> In the Left menu: Archiving action -> `Artifacts` -> There you choose what you want to download.

Happy testing